# ConcurrentHashMap as singletone cache with synchronized

Tags: java, android, multithreading, volatile, concurrenthashmap

how do you think, **do we need to use synchronized block for better optimization** of access to instance of Ad? 
The instance of Ad.class can be retrieved from different threads. Synchronized helps to get an instance in one time with one get operation from ConcurrentHashMap. ConcurrentHashMap store all values as volatile. I use it on java 1.7 for android, **computeIfAbsent** is available in java 1.8.

It will be great to get detailed answer, why not or why yes.
Thank you!

```
public final class Ad {

    private final static Map<String, Ad> ads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static Ad get(@NonNull String appId) {
        if (appId == null) appId = "";

        boolean containsAd = ads.containsKey(appId);

        Ad localInstance = containsAd ? ads.get(appId) : null;

        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Ad.class) {

                containsAd = ads.containsKey(appId);

                localInstance = containsAd ? ads.get(appId) : null;

                if (localInstance == null) {
                    localInstance = new Ad();
                    localInstance.setAdId(appId);
                    ads.put(appId, localInstance);
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    private Ad() {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to all for help. I replaced ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap.

Comment: If you read the javadocs, this class was designed to prevent locking. Synchronized block does not make sense. You might as well use a hash table

Comment: Yes, if you find yourself using `synchronized` and `ConcurrentHashMap` together, you're either not using `ConcurrentHashMap` correctly, or you should be using a non-threadsafe collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite optimal.  If multiple threads try initialize values at the same time, then they will block each other, even if they are looking for different keys.

You should use `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` to check for the add and create missing ones in a single step.  That way you will not create any Ads that aren't used, and two threads will only block each other if they're trying to initialize the same entry:

```
public static Ad get(@NonNull String appId) {
    if (appId == null) appId = "";

    return ads.computeIfAbsent(appId, Ad::new);
}

private Ad(String appId) {
    this();
    setAdId(appId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matt-timmermans, that's make sense. 
Does it mean that other threads will be blocked while I creating a new Ad in one thread and put it to ConcurrentHashMap for current key?
Sorry, I forgot to write that I use it on java 1.7 for android.
computeIfAbsent is available in java 1.8 (((

Comment: only threads that are trying to create ads (on the same *or different* keys) will be blocked, so it's not too bad if there aren't too many keys

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you actually want to achieve is `putIfAbsent` and as such this is *much* simpler then what you do (your are using a double check locking):

```
public static Ad get(String appId) {
    String newId = appId == null ? "" : appId;
    ads.putIfAbsent(newId, new Ad());
    return map.get(newId);
}
```

Comment: With this code, `Ad.get()` would return `null` if the map didn't have a mapping for `appId`. I don't think that is ideal.

Comment: if `newId` does not exist in the map, `putIfAbsent` is going to return `null`, and your `get()` method will also return `null`.

Comment: @SeanBright oh darn! I was thinking about `computeIfAbsent(newId, s -> new Ad())`, but wrote an entirely different thing - thank you for correcting me. But then this obviously is not atomic anymore

Comment: Now you have a race condition between `putIfAbsent` and `get`. If `remove` or `clear` is never called, it's probably fine, but just keep it in mind.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed that in your comment.